# Filling an array with selected items of another array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, applescript, applescript-objc

I'm just getting to know AppleScriptObj-C and trying to create a simple application that would allow me to create playlists.

The question is:
 I have an array, containing all the music tracks from my iTunes library viewed through NSTableView. I make a selection and want these selected items to be copied to another array. How do I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with AppleScriptObj-C, but I can give it to you in AppleScript...

```
tell application "iTunes" to set the array to the selection as list
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that the selection is made not in iTunes, but in a TableVeiw in my application.